# Official number of TeX.SE users

Tags: discussion, statistics

In these days I have asked myself one question:

*how many are the total users of **TeX.SE**?*

[image]

[image]

From the tables that I am attaching I do not see any global number.

Comment: What is *reputation change* in the top table? It looks very suspicious that the numbers in the top table very much resemble the numbers in the bottom table.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen I suppose that is the reputation change since the beginning of the site: https://stackexchange.com/leagues/85/alltime/tex

Comment: @Glorfindel Oh, I see. If one selects a shorter time period, the two tables will be more different. (That link really should have been in the question.)

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Hi, if you want you are authorized to change my question to be more clear. You're welcome.

Comment: @Glorfindel How is the all-time reputation change different from the total reputation (up to possibly the initial association bonus of 100 points)?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat the top table only takes users with 200+ rep into account (see the message at the bottom)

Comment: @Glorfindel Thanks! So the last two rows are completely redundant... and one may replace the last three rows by the information how many users gained 200+ points.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One global number in that list is the **179,089** users with 1 or more reputation (you can't have less than 1 reputation).

Another way to look at it is to check the [user list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all), note that it has 36 users per page and 4590 pages, which amounts to (a little less than) **165,240** users. I suspect unregistered accounts aren't listed here, hence the lower number.

The [Stack Exchange site list](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic) lists the number of users on each site, and for TeX.SE it gives **179k**:

[image]

The [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/1242112/number-of-users) says it's **178,499**, but SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday morning, so it lags a bit.

Finally, the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users#order=desc&sort=reputation&filter=!bWTmHuO_e2w(6G&site=tex) says the number is **179,092**. Very similar to the one from the reputation leagues, but probably less prone to caching.

Comment: Thank you very very much for your complete answer.